# how to create my own fingerprint for google maps embeded android application for public use

Tags: android, google-maps, keystore, api-key

My google maps embedded android app working correctly on emulator and real device but after signing my app and putting .apk file on the real device it dose not load google maps.I think that I have made some signing error.I have registered debug.keystore with google for getting google map API key.I searched internet for signing methods of google map embedded android app but I did not found any thing useful to me.I am publishing this app to the android market but this (google maps does not load on real device )problem stuck me.


So please any one help me that I can get google maps API key for public use and can properly 
sign this app .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Did you sign the app with your debug keystore value, or with a release keystore?  Google seems to indicate V3 doesn't need a key: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need a different maps API key when you release an android application.

I quote:

Keep in mind that each Maps API Key is uniquely associated with a specific signing certificate. That means that:

•When you are getting started on developing, you can register using the debug certificate created by the SDK tools.

•When you are ready to publish your application, you need to register again using the certificate with which you will sign your application for release. You must then update your MapView elements so that they reference the release API Key, rather than the debug Key, and then sign your application with your release certificate.

Above quote is found here:
http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html

Below webpage tells you how to get MD5 fingerprint for your signing certificate 
http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getfingerprint